# Create an associative array of unique values and their counts from a flat array

Tags: php, arrays, count, unique, associative-array

How can I get number of counts for each unique items?

Example:

```
$array = [
    "bye",
    "bye",
    "bye",
    "hello",
    "hello"
];
```

Desired result:

```
['bye' => 3, 'hello' => 2]
```

Comment: This is an obviously incorrect dupe closure.  I'm not saying that there isn't a suitable dupe for this question, but the current dupe target does not resolve the asked question.

Answer (score 32):

If you want to get the total count of unique values in a specified column within a given array, as a simple integer (rather than another array) try something simple like this:

```
$uniqueCount = count(array_unique(array_column($data, 'column_name'))); 

// (where $data is your original array, and column_name is the column you want to cycle through to find the total unique values in whole array.)  

var_dump(array_count_values(array("bye", "bye", "bye", "hello", "hello")));
```

Comment: You can clean up the output of this method to get what you want by saving what array_count_values() gives you into an array and then looping over each item in that array and outputting the key = value.

Comment: how to count the number of items for each distinct column_name ?

Answer (score 30):

You can use [array_count_values](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php).

```
print_r(array_count_values($array));
```

will return :

```
Array
(
    [bye] => 3
    [hello] => 2
)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`array_count_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) on your array which would return something like:

```
array(2){
    ["bye"]=> int(3)
    ["hello"]=> int(2)
}
```

Example Usage:

```
$unique = array_count_values($my_array);
```