# How to get SQL-like HAVING and GROUP BY for PHP arrays?

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a PHP code snippet or a built in array function that would do kind of like what a sql statement with having and group by does? That is removing the dups and counting the occurrences and giving you back an array that you can use for reporting/debugging purposes.

An example may clarify;

say your array is like this

```
Array (
['0'] => usa
['1'] => minnesota
['2'] => california
['3'] => san fransisco
['4'] => los angeles
['5'] => san fransisco
['6'] => malibu
['7'] => malibu
['8'] => malibu
['9'] => usa
}
```

and you want something back like this, or something to this effect..

```
Array (
['usa'] => 2
['minnesota'] => 1
['california'] => 1
['san fransisco'] => 2
['los angeles'] => 1
['malibu'] => 3
}
```

Comment: You have to work on your `<insert favourite search engine here>` skills. `php array count values` led me straight to this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - count frequency of array values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034889/php-count-frequency-of-array-values), [Is there a PHP function to count the number of times a value occurs within an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9073504/218196), [What is a clever way to count number of unique items in array (PHP)?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5553981/218196) and [Count number of values in array with a given value](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1317612/218196)

Comment: Actually, I need to improve my reading skills. Cause I went to the array-functions page on php.net. Saw the count_values but did not click on it. When you are on rush, it's easy to miss things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

You can use the following code to do this:

```
array_count_values ($myArray)
```

Comment: Yeah... beat me too, But i ain't deleting mine :P

Comment: PHP has such an rich 'array' of functions

Comment: David Z got it first! Thank you all everybody! This PHP is one heck of a lang.

Answer (score 1):

Doing it manually:

```
$new = array();
foreach($array as $key => $val) {
  if (!isset($new[$key]) {
    $new[$key] = 0;
  }
  $new[$key]++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`array_count_values()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) to get the number of duplicates

```
$array = array(...);
$duplicate = array_count_values($array);
```